# How does $0 < 1/j$ and $1/k < 1/N$ imply that $| 1/j - 1/k | \leq 1/N$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

**Synopsis**

In Tao's *Analysis 1*, in his proof that the sequence $a_1,a_2, a_3, \dots$ defined by $a_n := 1/n$ is a Cauchy sequence, there is an inequality that I don't really feel comfortable with. I'll highlight this inequality below the proof and give some insight later.

*Proof*

We have to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, the sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots$ is eventually $\epsilon$-steady. So let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. We now have to find a number $N \geq 1$ such that the sequence $a_N, a_{N+1}, \dots$ is $\epsilon$-steady. This means that $d(a_j, a_k) \leq \epsilon$ for every $j,k \geq N$, i.e. $$|1/j - 1/k| \leq \epsilon \text{ for every $j,k \geq N$}.$$ Now since $j,k \geq N$, we know that $0<1/j$, $1/k < 1/N$, so that $|1/j - 1/k| \leq 1/N$. So it is sufficient for $N$ to be greater than $1/ \epsilon$.

*The Inequality*

The inequality that if $0<1/j$ and $1/k \leq 1/N$ is true, then $|1/j - 1/k| \leq 1/N$ is true just doesn't click for me. Probably it's my lack of sleep, but the intuition isn't there. I have, however, been able to prove it partially (I think, though there's probably something wrong since I'm mentally so incapacitated), and I'll highlight my partial proof below.

*Partial Proof of Inequality That Is Probably Obvious to Most People Who Are Not Me*

Suppose $j \geq k$. Then $1/j \leq 1/k$. So $1/N \geq 1/k > 1/k - 1/j = |1/j - 1/k|$ (since $1/j - 1/k < 0$). Now suppose $k <j$. Then by a similar argument, $1/N \geq 1/j \geq 1/j - 1/k = |1/j - 1/k|$ (isn't $1/j \leq 1/N$ since both $j,k \geq N$? I hope  so.). Therefore, $|1/j - 1/k | < 1/N$.

*Finale*

As you can see, $|1/j - 1/k | < 1/N$ is slightly different from $|1/j - 1/k | \leq 1/N$. What's wrong with my "proof"? Why is my brain so bewildered by this inequality that probably isn't even that important? What is some intuition for this?

**EDIT**

I now realize that I simply suck at reading textbooks and that Tao was implying that $0<1/j<1/N$ and $0<1/k<1/N$ were both true at the same time wow I am actually a mess right now. This is now so painfully obvious and I cannot believe I spent like 15 minutes just bewildered. Thank you so much for your kind answers.

Comment: With your interpretation, the inequality is false.

Comment: Oof. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you're missing is this: when Tao writes

> we know that $0 < 1/j, 1/k < 1/N$ is true

he means that there are two inequalities that are true, namely
$$
0 < 1/j < 1/N \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0 < 1/k < 1/N.
$$
So, now you have two numbers, $1/j$ and $1/k$, sandwiched strictly between $0$ and $1/N$. So, the distance between these two "inner numbers" is definitely smaller than the distance between the two "outer numbers", that is,
$$
\lvert 1/j - 1/k \rvert < 1/N - 0 = 1/N.
$$

Comment: This is now so obvious I cannot believe I spent so much time trying to figure out what Tao meant. Wow I really suck at reading in between the lines.

Comment: It happens to all of us, don't beat yourself up over it :) Kudos to you for formulating your question so neatly!

Comment: You are too kind! Thanks for the encouragement :D

Answer (score 4):

There, $0<1/j, 1/k < 1/N$ has the following meaning:

$0<1/j < 1/N$ and $0<1/k < 1/N$.

Comment: Wow. I really overcomplicated this.

Comment: I suck at reading textbooks.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would think about this fact is that that since $j,k\ge N$ we know that $\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{j}\le\frac{1}{N}$ and so since we are looking at two numbers smaller than $\frac{1}{N}$ (and strictly bigger than 0), they cannot possibly be further apart than $\frac{1}{N}$; the distinction between $<$ and $\le$ in the proof seems to not matter (certainly the former implies the latter).